# Entering Unicode data in Visual Studio, C#

Tags: visual-studio, unicode

Is there a good way to type Unicode symbols in a C# file?

I'm looking for something to the effect of:

1. Press ALT
2. Type Unicode Hex
3. Release Alt

Currently, I'm having to type the symbol into word and copy-paste it into my source file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\uFFFF
\UFFFFFFFF
```

[C# Unicode character escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences).

Comment: This link is broken, and the landing page disables the back button.

Comment: The approach is sound, but I concur with the follow up; link broken. Thank you for the tip however.

Answer (score 6):

The [answer of Neutrino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653870/4973073) activated the Alt+Numpad input method ([Microsoft Glossary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/goglobal/bb964658.aspx)), but I had to search for the correct registry path. It is:

> 2. Navigate to HKC**U**\Control Panel\Input Method

I tried to write a Unicode-char within my comments in source (. 
Unfortunately I cannot enter a Unicode code point, like shown in `charmap`, to get the corresponding character.

- Using [Alt]+[+]+<xxxx>, where the hexadecimal Unicode code point (4-figure) replaces the xxxx, does not enter any character (neither [Numpad +] nor regular [+] key), when using the *regular* numeric keys.
- Meanwhile using *Numpad* for the 4-figured code (it has digits only), it is irrelevant to hit [+] before entering the Unicode code point. It just writes the same character like without preceding [+] (or in my case with preceding zero [0]). The entered character is the one defined in the codepage.
- Just for curiosity I have tried also using the decimal code (0x2192 = 8594) or switching the codepage via `chcp`. But it does not change anything.

Unluckily I find no way to convince Windows to enter the char with its U+xxxx code presented  within Windows' own `charmap`.
Luckily, there people share this problem over multiple programs, not just Visual Studio. So the folks at http://www.fileformat.info provide several tipps in [an article for Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm), among them a self written [UnicodeInput Utility](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm) which solves it.
Though I still think, Windows should have an built-in solution.

(PS: I would have added a comment, but my reputation is still too low.)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that Visual Studio, by default, does not allow the use of many of the ALT codes.  The work around is to just paste in the Unicode symbol.
1) run charmap.exe.
2) click advanced view.
3) search for the symbol you want (by name or code number).
4) copy the symbol you want.
5) paste it into your document.

charmap.exe comes standard with windows.  You can use it to insert any Unicode symbol.

Comment: Cool, I recognize the look of the program, but didn't know that it was a separate program you could run like that. Very handy!

Answer (score 3):

I have to say that I don't think the selected answer actually answers the question at all. Entering the Unicode code point as a escape sequence in a string literal does not result in the Unicode symbol appearing in the file. Adding an escape sequence to a literal and typing the symbol are two different things.

A better answer is:

1. Open RegEdit
2. Navigate to HKCR\Control Panel\Input Method
3. Create string key EnableHexNumpad with value "1" (no quotes).
4. Reboot.

Now in any source file to type a Unicode symbol hold down ALT and type numpad plus followed by the hexadecimal code point then release ALT.

E.g. For © hold ALT and enter +00a9.

Works in most windows apps, including Firefox :)

Comment: or hold alt and type the decimal code for the character

Comment: This only works for me if the code point only consists of digits, such as 1111. However, as soon as a letter such as A is required, the associated menu appears.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste from the Unicode article on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use Unicode hex in the Visual Studio code window is to type the HTML entity hex (for example **&#x26ab;** ), then select the text, right click (or use Edit menu), and choose "Encode Selection > HTML Decode". It will convert the text into the specified character.

Answer (score 1):

**Unicode can be typed into Windows using the hexadecimal code.**

Type the four-digit Unicode hexadecimal code
- then press [Alt][X]
- The digits will be replaced with the Unicode character.
- The only requirement is that Application can use Unicode.
Example:
Code 00a9 - Character ©
Type 00a9
Press [Alt]+[X]
© - is typed

Window will accept most Unicode syntax
Example:
00a9
a9
u+00a9
- etc.

In Windows, there are other ways to type Ascii and Unicode, including Emjois.

**1)** ASCII codes (Traditional Alt+KeyPad method)
- Hold [Alt] - type the code on numpad:
Example:
[Alt]0169 (release Alt)
©

- Some codes require the leading 0
  For example, 'Copyright,' is ASCII code 0169
  the leading 0 is part of the code
  As 169 is '⌐' and 0169 is '©'
- Combination codes can also be entered this way,
  and chaining codes for more advanced entry.
- If your laptop doesn't have a Num/KeyPad,
  Enable the Fn NumPad. It is usually these keys.

  ```
  7 8 9
  u i o
  j k l
  , . /
  ```

**2)** [Win]+[.] - Is a newer input feature that provides access to common symbols and Emojis, GIFs, etc.

**3)** The Touch Keyboard also has the same interface and functionality as [Win]+[.]

**4)** The On-Screen Keyboard is another solution. Unlike Touch and other input modals, it provides keyboard functionality similar a keyboard.

**5)** Type Unicode code
Example:
u+0023 - Press [Alt]+[X]

*PS There are other ways to access Unicode characters in Windows. Window has also supported Unicode as long as NT has existed.
Example: Via other input devices, scripting. i.e.
- PowerShell,
- ANSI/Terminal Escape characters.*

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking how to do this in Linux, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`U`, then type the code, and finally press `Space` or `Enter`, then the character will appear. Works with every application.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can enter ALT+dddd where dddd is the four digits of the unicode character number in decimal. For example, pressing 0170 while holding down the ALT key results in entering ª.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode does not support Unicode input. Use Wordpad to input the unicode character, then copy to VSCode. Otherwise, you can also use plugin if this is a more frequent action. See more details from my guide [here](https://dev.to/patfinder/keyboard-ancient-secrets-5g7k).

Comment: While you are currently abiding by the promotion rules, be careful not to overly promote. If you continue to promote your blog, it may be seen as overly promotional, and can result in your answers being considered spam, regardless of disclosure. Don't worry though, **as of right now, you have done nothing wrong**, just make sure not to overly promote yourself.

Comment: what do you mean "does not support unicode input"? obviously it does. It just doesn't provide any builtin feature for entering codepoints and getting the corresponding character. if you want to type the digits for a codepoint and then get the character, you need something else.