# In VB I want to use Unicode characters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, character-encoding, console-application

I am having a problem, when I try to enter Japanese characters into the VB console they show up as question marks with no data attached to them. I am writing a program to help me conjugate words and I need to be able to input Japanese characters to do so.

Is there a setting I can change to allow the input and output of these characters?

Comment: Are you speaking about VB.NET or VBA (Office Applications)? Because you had both in your tags and these are completely different applications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entering Unicode data in Visual Studio, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239712/entering-unicode-data-in-visual-studio-c-sharp)

Comment: Is your issue the input or the output? If you are referring to the actual console output, the console may simply not have the font required to display the characters. In such cases it will show as ???

Comment: The issue is both input and output

Comment: As far as I know you cannot type them directly in the code editor. Instead you can use the `ChrW` function with the unicode like `strW = ChrW(&H25B2) & "More text"`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the the solution!

1. Add the following code to the top of your code:

```
    Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode

    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
```

This will allow the *input* of foreign characters but it won't allow you to see the actual characters, (the characters will just have value)

2. Run the code
3. At the top left of the console, there is a an icon, click it, and then click [properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcQ5k.png)
4. Go to the font tab and change the font. So far, the ones that work for me are any that begin with "MS", but "SimSun-ExtB" works too.
5. Click "Ok" and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) has a reference for several unicode ranges.

You can try my method as follows. Please pay attention to `RichTextBox1.Text &= (ChrW(i))` which is the most important step.
[image]

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim First_Unicode, Last_unicode As Integer

    'Hexadecimal to Decimal
    Public Function H2D(ByVal Hex As String) As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Dim b As Long

        Hex = UCase(Hex)
        For i = 1 To Len(Hex)
            Select Case Mid(Hex, Len(Hex) - i + 1, 1)
                Case "0" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 0
                Case "1" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 1
                Case "2" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 2
                Case "3" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 3
                Case "4" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 4
                Case "5" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 5
                Case "6" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 6
                Case "7" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 7
                Case "8" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 8
                Case "9" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 9
                Case "A" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 10
                Case "B" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 11
                Case "C" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 12
                Case "D" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 13
                Case "E" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 14
                Case "F" : b = b + 16 ^ (i - 1) * 15
            End Select
        Next i
        H2D = b
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RichTextBox1.Font = New Font("Cambria", 20, FontStyle.Regular)

        First_Unicode = H2D(TextBox1.Text)
        Last_unicode = H2D(TextBox2.Text)

        'display 20 characters each line 
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = First_Unicode To Last_unicode
            RichTextBox1.Text &= (ChrW(i))
            If i Mod 20 = 0 Then
                RichTextBox1.Text &= vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```